# Extract vertices from an ARC in generic way

Tags: javascript, algorithm, geometry, bresenham, rasterize

I want to get all the vertices from an ARC. I have all the data (for ex : start point, end point, start angle, end angle, radius) which will used to draw an arc but my need is I have to generate all the vertices from the arc data.

I have already tried with one or two algorithm but I failed to get the exact vertices from an arc data.

I used Bresenham's algorithm but I failed.

Right now I am using below code but its not working ..

```
            double theta = 2 * 3.1415926 / 100; 
            double c = Math.cos(theta);
            double s = Math.sin(theta);
            double t;

            double x = ((ArcTo) element).getRadius();//we start at angle = 0 
            double y = 0; 

            for(int ii = 0; ii < 100; ii++) { 
              coordinates.add(new Coordinate(x + element.getCenterPoint().getX(), y + element.getCenterPoint().getY()));//output vertex 

              //apply the rotation matrix
              t = x;
              x = c * x - s * y;
              y = s * t + c * y;
            }
```

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: The simplest way is using Bresenham's algorithm.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Thanx for your reply. I have already tried with that but its not working for arc.

Comment: Post your code with implementation of Bresenham's algo.  Say what exactly is not working.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff You can find my code here - http://jsfiddle.net/shiladittya/qb4528cq/. Its draw a circle but I want to draw an arc instead of create a circle. I have all the variable which are necessary to draw an arc.

Answer (score 0):

1. **First some clarifications**

   I assume that by **vertices** you mean the pixels and **ARC** is standard **2D** circular arc **(not elliptic arc !!!)** and your input data are:

   ```cpp
   int (x0,y0),(x1,y1) // star/end points on curve !!!
   float a0,a1         // start end angles [rad]
   int (xc,yc)         // center of circle
   int r               // radius
   ```
2. **Do not use Bresenham**

   because you would need to start from zero angle and compute all pixels until start point is hit. Then flip draw flag so you start filling  the pixel from that point and stop on end point hit. Also you would need to handle the winding to match **ARC** direction.
3. **You can use circle parametric equation**

   ```cpp
   // just some arc data to test with
   float r=25.0;
   float a0= 45.0*M_PI/180.0;
   float a1=270.0*M_PI/180.0;
   int xc=100,x0=xc+floor(r*cos(a0)),x1=xc+floor(r*cos(a1));
   int yc=100,y0=yc+floor(r*sin(a0)),y1=yc+floor(r*sin(a1));
   // arc rasterize code
   int x,y;
   float a,da;
   // here draw pixels x0,y0 and x1,y1 to avoid rounding holes ...
   if (r) da=0.75/float(r); else da=0.1; // step slightly less then pixel to avoid holes
   for (a=a0;;a+=da)
    {
    x=xc+int(floor(r*cos(a)));
    y=yc+int(floor(r*sin(a)));
    // here draw pixel x,y
    if ((x==x1)&&(y==y1)) // stop if endpoint reach
     if (fabs(a-a1)<da)   // but ignore stop if not at end angle (full or empty circle arc)
      break;
    }
   ```

   may be `round` instead of `floor` will have less pixel position error. If your endpoint does not match then this will loop infinitely. If you tweak a bit the end conditions you can avoid even that or recompute `x1,y1` from `a1` as I have ...
4. **You can use equation `(x-xc)^2+(y-yc)^2=r^2`**

   you need to divide **ARC** to quadrants and handle each as separate arc looping through `x` or `y` and computing the other coordinate. Loop through coordinate that is changing more

   [image: dx,dy quadrants]

   so in blue areas loop `y` and in the red loop `x`. For example red area code can look like this:

   ```cpp
   int x,y;
   for (x=_x0;;x++)
    {
    y=sqrt((r*r)-((x-xc)*(x-xc)));
    // here draw pixel x,y
    if (x==_x1) // stop if endpoint reach
     break;
    }
   ```

   you need to compute `(_x0,_y0),(_x1,_y1)` start end points of cut part of **ARC** inside the quadrant and make `_x0<=_x1`.

   The value for `_x` looped start/end point coordinate will be `xc +/- sqrt(r)` or `x0` or `x1`

   the value for `_y` looped start/end point coordinate will be `yc +/- sqrt(r)` or `y0` or `y1`

   The blue parts are done in analogically manner (just swap/replace `x` and `y`). This approach is a bit more complicated due to cutting but can be done solely on integers. `sqrt` can be speed up by **LUT** (limiting the max radius) and the `^2` can be also further optimized.

**[Notes]**

so if I recapitulate the parametric equation is the simplest to implement but slowest. Then is the `sqrt` approach which can be done as fast as Bresenham (and may be even faster with **LUT**) but need the code for cutting **ARC** to quadrants which need few `if`s prior to rendering.

All codes are in **C++** and can be further improved like avoiding some `int/float` conversions, pre-compute  some values before loop, etc ...

The last goes the Bresenham but you need to change a few things inside and when you do not know what you are doing you can easily get lost. It also need to cut to octant's so the complexity of change is far bigger then `sqrt` approach